# Which statistical test? - noobie question

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm very new to statistics. I have data from some field work and need to test for statistical significant relationships using SPSS. The data is looking for a relationship between urban park quality and human wellbeing. One variable is the wellbeing score which varies, the other is the quality score of the park which is constant. Can anyone advice on which test I should use in SPSS??

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV! _One variable is the wellbeing score which varies, the other is the quality score of the park which is constant._ Can you explain this? I don't understand what it means for a _variable_ to be _constant_.

Comment: Hi Utobi, thanks for the reply. I may be using the wrong terminology. I have a column of data of peoples wellbeing scores from a particular park, that changes per person. I also have the quality score for that park, that value remains the same.

I have four parks, each with a quality score and 61 wellbeing scores. I want to see if there is a statistical relationship between the quality score of a park and the wellbeing score of the people.

Since posting my original question I read about chi-squared. Could that be the test I need to perform?